# What is the adjective for "sent down" or "descend"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, adjectives

The only word I found is *descendant* but this is often used for people, and I want to use the word for objects. Is there an adjective or alternative I can use if I want to say *sent down*, *brought down* as an adjective? It seems the word *descended* does not exist.

Comment: Can you construct a sentence where the word would go?

Comment: Look for phrases like "descended testicle(s)" and "undescended testicle(s)" (cryptorchidism) and you'll find the adjective you're seeking.

Answer (score 6):

OP shouldn't worry about the fact that [descendant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descendant) is often used of people. That Wikipedia disambiguation page lists several alternatives, of which the last two may match OP's context.

Google gives a lot of hits for ["a **descendant** class"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20descendant%20class%22&oq=%22a%20descendant%20class%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), few of which involve *people*.

Plus, as Bill comments, [a **descended** [testicle/larynx/god/etc.]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22glow%20with%20embarrassment%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22a%20descended%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=EBWkUOmDH4HN0QWCsoGYCg&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cde33c27fffa4867&bpcl=38626820&biw=1223&bih=893) is perfectly normal English.

For OP's context *(things which **have been sent/brought down**)*, perhaps **lowered** would suit.

The semantic differences there are mainly that a *descendant* normally derives from a "parent". Things which are *descended* usually got there by themselves (or by accident), whereas if something is ***lowered***, this normally implies that someone (or something) *actively caused it to go down*.

We don't really have OP's full context, but as Andrew comments below, *floored* sometimes works. As do *felled, downcast, saddened, ousted, humbled*, in various related contexts.

Comment: I'm not convinced. *Descended* generally means that the object has come down of its own accord or through natural process, **not** that it has been sent down or brought down by something else acting upon it -- which is what the OP asks about.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Fair enough - I'll add an alternative.

Comment: +1 again. It's just occurred to me that *floored* might also be applicable to some uses of "brought down".